# Find Specific Text from a middle of a string and store it into datatable or in List in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, split

I have a string as below

```
string error_message= "{\"2705\":\"Error importing username: 3167763, primary email: pkumar194@google.com, error: User already exists but Email does not match: pkumar194@googlee.com vs pkumar193@google.co.in\",\"10001\":\"Error importing username: 3195330, primary email: alejandra.mejia@google.com, error: User already exists but Email does not match: alejandra.mejia@google.com vs alejandra.mejia@googlee.com\"}";
```

from the above string i need to find the  repeating text "Error importing username:" and take the username value next to it  and store it in `int<list>` or in datatable with expected output as below

```
3167763
3195330
```

i have tried with below code but its working only when the ""Error importing username:" text appear once but in my case that text is reapeating and i need to get all the username in a list

Your help is very much needed ,Thanks in Advance

```
string error_message= "{\"2705\":\"Error importing username: 3167763, primary email: pkumar194@google.com, error: User already exists but Email does not match: pkumar194@googlee.com vs pkumar193@google.co.in\",\"10001\":\"Error importing username: 3195330, primary email: alejandra.mejia@google.com, error: User already exists but Email does not match: alejandra.mejia@google.com vs alejandra.mejia@googlee.com\"}";
string strStart = "Error importing username:";
string strEnd = ",";


if (error_msg.Contains(strStart) && error_msg.Contains(strEnd))
{
                                    
    int Start = error_msg.IndexOf(strStart) + strStart.Length;
    int End = error_msg.IndexOf(strEnd, Start);
    return error_msg.Substring(Start, End - Start);
}
```

Comment: If you use IndexOf instead of Contains, you can specify where the search should start - if you use the end of the last occurrence found, you can keep repeating the search until you find all occurrences. Or of course, just use Regex.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be Regex:

```
List<int> list = Regex.Matches(error_message, @"(?<=Error importing username: )\d+")
    .Select(match => int.Parse(match.Value))
    .ToList();
```

`(?<=Error importing username: )` is a positive look-behind that detects the text `Error importing username:`  but does not include it in the match.

`\d+` matches one or more digits.

[Working example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pPnnLg)

---

**Update**

In .Net Framework, `MatchCollection` does not implement `IEnumerable<Match>`
, so a `Cast<Match>()` is required:

```
List<int> list = Regex.Matches(error_message, @"(?<=Error importing username: )\d+")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(match => int.Parse(match.Value))
    .ToList();
```

[Working example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bbRrjx)

Comment: nice! much better than mine

Comment: i am getting below error when using ur code , could u pls help 

Error CS1061 'MatchCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'MatchCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)


i have used all required below namespace still getting this error
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

Comment: @7Mviews Probably because you're using .Net Framework rather than .Net Core. See my update.

Comment: along with username how can i fetch the corresponding primary email: value

 for Example "Error importing username: 3167763, primary email: pkumar194@google.com" 

for this i need the output as collection with user id and email in seperate columns

3167763  pkumar194@google.com





i tried different way but no luck, your help is very much appreciated

Comment: @7Mviews You could use Regex capturing groups, but you should really post this as a new question because the answer would be significantly different to the above.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay could you able to help me on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64965806/find-specific-text-and-coresponding-email-id-from-a-middle-of-a-string-and-store

Answer (score 0):

Well I think this should do it using linq. This is assuming the string `Error importing username:`  is in the `error_message`. Of course if the format of the input string changes it'd need some tweaking.

```
var ids = error_message.Split("Error importing username: ")
                .Skip(1)
                .Select(x => x.Split(",").First());
```